# How to declare Arduino array with custom type?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I use for my Arduino project [OneWire library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html) and [Dallas one](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library). This one defines an `DeviceAddress` type which can contains an OneWire device address. I would like to create an array to store my devices address and therefore be able to loop on them.

Following does not compile

```
DeviceAddress waterTempSensorAddress = { 0x28, 0xCA, 0x98, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0x51 };
DeviceAddress heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress   = { 0x28, 0xC4, 0xA8, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC6 };

DeviceAddress test[] = { waterTempSensorAddress, heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress };
```

The error is :

`pool_manager:62: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
 DeviceAddress test[] = { waterTempSensorAddress, heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress };
                                                                                  ^`

Is it possible to declare an Arduino-like array for this? Should I consider using another structure?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really custom type, it's just `typedef uint8_t DeviceAddress[8];` and arrays can't be copy constructed unlike classes.

Basically you have two simple ways to do it:

```
// #1
DeviceAddress test[] = { { 0x28, 0xCA, 0x98, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0x51 }, { 0x28, 0xC4, 0xA8, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC6 } };
// and eventually you can define:
DeviceAddress  *waterTempSensorAddress = test;
DeviceAddress  *heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress = test + 1;
```

But it's not so nice.

Another way is using pointers:

```
// #2
DeviceAddress waterTempSensorAddress = { 0x28, 0xCA, 0x98, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0x51 };
DeviceAddress heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress   = { 0x28, 0xC4, 0xA8, 0xCF, 0x05, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC6 };
DeviceAddress * test2[] = { &waterTempSensorAddress, &heatWaterSystemTemSensorAddress };
```

The first one is easier to use, second one is little bit less readable:

```
void da(DeviceAddress const& addr) { /*  ....  */ }

void something() {
  da(test[0]);  // #1

  da(*(test2[0])); // #2 
  da(test2[0][0]); // #2 (it's basically two dimensional array of DeviceAddress)
}
```

Anyway, it's all about the C++ basics.

Little bit harder way is to use container class.